# AngularJS addRow and save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I have a shopping cart webapp that uses AngularJS to both add a row, and to save the entire table to local storage when pressing the 'save' button. I found code on another site that is focused on doing exactly this (for the addRow part), but it's not working for me. Anyone have any ideas? If you need the AngularJS file I was given I can add that as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>AngularJS Shopping Cart</title>
<script src="js/angular10.js"></script>
<script>
    function CartController($scope) {
        $scope.books =[
            {title: 'Absolute Java',
                qty: 1, price: 114.95},
            {title: 'Pro HTML5',
                qty: 1, price: 27.95},
            {title: 'Head First HTML5',
                qty: 1, price: 27.89}
        ];
        $scope.rows =[
            {title: 'New Book', qty: 1, price: 10.99}
        ];
        $scope.removeBook = function(index) {
            $scope.books.splice(index, 1);
        }
        $scope.addRow = function() {
            $scope.rows.push($scope.rows);
          }
            }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ex05.css">
</head>
  <body ng-controller="CartController">
    <table>
    <caption><b>My Books</b></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>UnitPrice</th>
            <th>$UnitPrice</th>
            <th>Line Total</th>
            <th>Total </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="book in books">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="book.title" size="20">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="book.qty" size="2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="book.price" size="8">
            </td>
            <td>{{book.price | currency}}</td>
            <td>{{book.price * book.qty | currency}}</td>

            <td>
                <button ng-click="removeBook($index)">
                    Remove
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
<div id ="update">
    <button id="insert" ng-click="addRow()">
            New
        </button>
    <button id="save" ng-click="save">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly means not working ? the push??? you are sending an array instead the content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your add new row:

```
 $scope.addRow = function() {
  $scope.inserted = {
    title: "",
    qty: "",
    price: ""
   };
   $scope.books.push($scope.inserted);
 };
```

Comment: Should the HTML code for the button be different? Or should I get rid of the array part?

Comment: I don't suppose you could point me in the right direction to get the total from all the prices so it updates whenever a new book is added?

Comment: @user121168 is your problem still existing? I will try to give you an answer.